# Change keyboard layout with xmodmap or xbidnkeys

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xbindkeys

I need to use Numlock to switch between keyboard layouts.

Any way to achieve this with Xmodmap or Xbindkeys?

I tried `setxkbmap -layout` but it doesn't seem to provide a "switch between" functionality.

Comment: Does it have to be NumLock? Do you need the NumLock functionality?

Comment: @danzel I've never used the numlock key in my entire life (not literally but still to a huge extent) and I can live without it, so I figured it's the best key to switch between layouts and please don't talk me out of it xD

Comment: Which Ubuntu version (and flavour), which display manager (wayland or Xorg)? Never thought about it, but I think this is the least used key on my keyboard too.

Comment: @danzel Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Xorg :)